# Meteor deploy android app on galaxy

Tags: android, meteor

I have a beginners question.

I deployed my `meteor` website on `Galaxy`. Now I want an android version of my website. I followed every step in mobile docs. Everything is working fine on windows and the app is working as expected in the emulator.

Now if I build my app for production, we need to give a host and port.
What port and host should I use so I can use the same code base as my website?

Here is [My domain](http://heybuddy.meteorapp.com/)

I tried:

```
meteor build ../output --server http://heybuddy.meteorapp.com:80
```

But without success. Or do I see it totally wrong.

Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

The host is where your server is accessible, typically the address you use to access the browser-based version of your application / website.

The port is not mandatory.